# Customising Microsoft Word punctuation checks

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

I need to spell check documents about SQL Server applications. These will often mention "database..table". How do I get Word to ignore the double full stops?

Comment: Which version of Word?

Comment: Sorry, Word 2003

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any ways of stopping only some punctuation checks, but you can stop all of them. Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Spelling & Grammar**, find the **Settings...** button and uncheck **Punctuation** from the list.

This might be a bit extreme, but I don't know any other methods. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks alex but I think this is a bit extreme for me, I'm a too bad a typist fo throw away punctuation checks

Comment: Thought so :). Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace ".." with " " (blank)
Or you can easily select "database..table", hit Ctrl+C to copy then Ctrl+F to open the Find and Replace window, then select Replace tab to replace with "database table"

Additionally you can try to use the Special feature Find What Text

[image: Find and Replace | Special | Find What Text]

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. In SQL Server 'database..table' is a legitimate name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What do you mean by ignoring the double full stop?

Comment: I'm mean for the spell checker not to highlight it as a grammar mistake

Answer (score 0):

Under the spell checker, you can add "database..table" to your personal dictionary and ensure that Word uses both the standard dictionary and personal dictionary to check.  Then when it is found in your personal dictionary, it will ignore it as ok.

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer - 'database' and 'table' are variables.

Comment: @user9879 - It's not too late to edit your question...